# Does the PHP date() function format the time to the current locale settings

Tags: php, date, deprecated, strftime

I am trying to use the `date()` function as an alternative to the now deprecated `strftime()` function, and I need to know whether the `date()` function formats the time like the `strftime()` function according to the locale time.

[strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

As said by php.net in the `strftime()` manual:

> strftime — Format a local time/date according to locale settings

But in the `date()` function manual [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it only says:

> date — Format a Unix timestamp

So does it format the Unix timestamp to the locale settings?

Comment: No, all output is in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on StackOverflow.

`Date` formats a Unix timestamp.
Unix timestamp means seconds from epoch.
Epoch is the Thursday, 01 January 1970 00:00:01.000
Where I live (CET), this is the Thursday, 01 January 1970 00:00:01.000 +01:00, so it depends on your locale

```php
echo date(DATE_RFC2822,0); //return Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 +0000
```

But if you set your locale, result is different:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('CET');
echo date(DATE_RFC2822,0); //return Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 +0100
```

About the languages, this method does not use "locales". All outputs are in English.

Answer (score 1):

You already linked the perfect source for information on that matter.

The format information on the `date()` docs page points to the `DateTimeeInterface::format` page (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) that [states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-notes):

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.